# Qt QML distinct URIs within a module

Tags: qt, cmake, qml

Is it possible for one to create a single module which supports multiple URIs?

Something like:

```
qt_add_qml_module(proj1
    URI proj1
    QML_FILES qml/Debug1.qml)

qt_target_qml_sources(proj1
    URI proj1.extra
    QML_FILES qml/x/Debug2.qml)
```

with a QML consuming it like:

```
import proj1
import proj1.extra as Extra

Item {
    Extra.Debug2 {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to make a second module for that purpose?

Comment: Yes.  The QML is all used together, it's merely for organization.  Why have 2x the CMakeLists in that case.  Also (separate issue), one module consuming another is giving me grief

Comment: A single module definitely can't have multiple URIs, as each module results in a single qmldir file. Inside a qmldir, you can only define a single URI address. and your only option is to define multiple modules.

Comment: Also, it is worth mentioning that you can add multiple libraries inside a single *CMakeLists* file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical answer to my question is no.

Functionally, however, what @JarMan implies and @smr suggests gets close enough for me when put into one `CMakeLists.txt`

Solution looks something like:

```
project(proj1-meta)

qt_add_qml_module(proj1
    URI proj1
    QML_FILES qml/Debug1.qml)

qt_add_qml_module(proj1-extra
    URI proj1.extra
    QML_FILES qml/x/Debug2.qml)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} proj1plugin proj1-extraplugin)
```

Requiring all the extra linking and setup that each Qt module needs.  I aggregated them all into one meta project to simulate one library.